# How to encrypt connection string in SubSonic 3.0

Tags: .net, encryption, app-config

I use SubSonic v.3 for my data access and I want to know how can I encryption my connection string in App.config used by SubSonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Subsonic, nor is it in any way different for Subsonic vs. other providers.

It's a .NET feature - you can encrypt parts of your `app.config` or `web.config` in such a way that the data becomes unreadable to the human eye, but can still be used by the .NET runtime to find the settings.

Check out Jon Galloway's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx) on how to encrypt parts of your `app.config` in a .NET application.